# CORS origin allowed parameters maintenance

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee, cors, jax-rs

I've created an JAXRS REST API on my JEE server. So, in order to be able to receive cross origin requests, I've added a filter provider in order to accept CORS requests:

```
@Provider
public class CORSFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter
{

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException
    {   
        responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, content-type, accept, authorization");
        responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD");
        responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1209600");
    }

}
```

I've also created a single page web application (SPWA) (located at `localhost:3000`) where I'm trying to get information from my REST endpoint located at `localhost:8082`.

So, browser is detecting I'm trying to get information crossing origins. So it's trying to first `OPTIONS` the request I'm trying to send (check is a user exists).

This is the CORS request browser is trying to send to my server:

```
Host: localhost:8082
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Access-Control-Request-Method: PUT
Access-Control-Request-Headers: passwd,user
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Connection: keep-alive
```

As you can see on `Filter Provider`, I'm allowing these headers:

```
responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, content-type, accept, authorization");
```

So, the question is:

1. My REST endpoint is going to grow, and each time I add a method with parameters, I'm going to have to check and update `"Access-Control-Allow-Headers"` -> I think is a very hard task.
2. Is there some way to trust some origins and avoid browser first send an `OPTIONS` request each time a request is made.

I hope I've explained so well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1.My REST endpoint is going to grow, and each time I add a method with parameters, I'm going to have to check and update "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" -> I think is a very hard task.

You have to include only the allowed headers your server is able to manage
(there are not so much. About 30 are standard in this [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields)). Usually a new business methods will not require a new header because they usually work with the payload. Mostly of the headers are managed by the container or JAX-RS you are using.

> 2. Is there some way to trust some origins and avoid browser first send an OPTIONS request each time a request is made.

**CORS requests are preflighted using an OPTIONS request**. See [Preflighted requests at Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests). In your example, a `PUT` request with `application/xml` also will be preflighted even it is requested in the same origing

> Unlike simple requests (discussed above), "preflighted" requests first send an HTTP request by the OPTIONS method to the resource on the other domain, in order to determine whether the actual request is safe to send. **Cross-site requests are preflighted like this since they may have implications to user data**. In particular, a request is preflighted if:
>
> - It uses methods other than GET, HEAD or POST. Also, if POST is used to send request data with a Content-Type other than application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, or text/plain, e.g. if the POST request sends an XML payload to the server using application/xml or text/xml, then the request is preflighted.
> - It sets custom headers in the request (e.g. the request uses a header such as X-PINGOTHER)